# How to make data inside a particular item show while using ng-repeat in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-material

I'm trying to make a quiz application with angular js.
When a user selects the correct answer i want to show an icon inside that item.
Problem is that icon is beign applied to every item in the list.
How can i fix this.?

here's the code

```
   <md-radio-group ng-model="test.selected" ng-change="test.onChange(test.selected)">
   <md-radio-button ng-repeat="item in test.items" value="{{item}}" class="md-accent" ng-click="test.validate($index)">
   {{item}}
   <md-icon class="material-icons md-secondary right" ng-show="test.isCorrect">done</md-icon>
   <md-icon class="material-icons md-secondary wrong" ng-show="test.isNotCorrect">clear</md-icon>
   </md-radio-button>
   </md-radio-group>
```

Here's a plunker demo [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sFYx9yh7wpWJJLrovupS?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes in your plunker,

[Changed link](http://plnkr.co/edit/Iia646OfraWaitSZiGQ0?p=preview)

```
(function(){
    angular.module('app')
            .controller('testCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
                var vm = this;
                vm.items = ['Dignity','Pretty','Cheap','Expensive'];
                vm.right = 0;
                vm.onChange = function(selected){
                        console.log(selected);
                    }
                vm.validate = function(index){
                    console.log(index);
                    if(index === vm.right){
                        vm.isCorrect = vm.items[index];
                        vm.isNotCorrect = "";
                    }
                    else{
                        vm.isNotCorrect = vm.items[index];
                        vm.isCorrect = "";
                    }
                }
            }])
})();
```

and in view

```
<md-icon class="material-icons md-secondary right" ng-show="test.isCorrect==item">done</md-icon>
<md-icon class="material-icons md-secondary wrong" ng-show="test.isNotCorrect==item">clear</md-icon>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick way could be to add the following styles:

```
md-icon {
  display: none !important;
}

.md-checked md-icon {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

They ensure that an icon is only shown under `md-checked` element.